# Crystal reports formula field not displaying if previous record field is same

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to Cystal reports.

I have a formula field which basically converts a number to date.

The formula field does not display if the previous record has same value.

Any idea what is missing?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Found the solution.. right click -> format field -> common tab ->Suppress if duplicated

Answer (score 0):

**8-digit numeric format  YYYYMMDD Datevalue**

WhilePrintingRecords;

NumberVar input := {table.StartDate}; // or whatever your field name is

// This line checks for a minimum value, any value will work.

If input < 19590101 then Date (1959, 01, 01) else

Date ( Val (ToText (input, 0 , "") [1 to 4]),

Val (ToText (input, 0 , "") [5 to 6]),

Val (ToText (input, 0 , "") [7 to 8]) )